# How to use chain for several transformations, including creating new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, method-chaining

Edited to comply with the rules:

How can I chain the following code? I cannot seem to be able to add new column with chain.

Input columns of Dataset:

ORDER, ITEM_SERIAL, DATE

```
%%time

df = Dataset.groupby(['ORDER', pd.Grouper(key='DATE', freq='7d')]).agg(Min=('DATE','min'), Max=('DATE','max'), ITEM_SERIAL_Min=('ITEM_SERIAL','first'), ITEM_SERIAL_Max=('ITEM_SERIAL','last')).reset_index()
                     
df['DIFFERENCE'] = df['Max'] - df['Min']
df = df[df['DIFFERENCE']!='0s'].sort_values('DIFFERENCE')
df = df.drop('DATE', axis=1)
df['ORDER'] = df['ORDER'] + '_' + df['Min'].map(str).str[:10]

df
```

Output columns of df:

ORDER, Min, Max, ITEM_SERIAL_Min, ITEM_SERIAL_Max, DIFFERENCE

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is quite subjective, but you could chain all operations in a formatted way (and add comments!):

```
df = (
    Dataset
    # groupby and aggregate ...
    .groupby(['ORDER', pd.Grouper(key='DATE', freq='7d')], as_index=False)
    .agg(
        Min=('DATE', 'min'),
        Max=('DATE', 'max'),
        ITEM_SERIAL_Min=('ITEM_SERIAL', 'first'),
        ITEM_SERIAL_Max=('ITEM_SERIAL', 'last'),
    )
    # compute DIFFERENCE ...
    .assign(DIFFERENCE=lambda d: d['Max'] - d['Min'])
    # filter ...
    .loc[lambda d: d['DIFFERENCE'] != '0s']
    # sort rows by ascending DIFFERENCE
    .sort_values('DIFFERENCE')
    # remove DATE column
    .drop('DATE', axis=1)
    # compute ORDER ...
    .assign(ORDER=lambda d: d['ORDER'] + '_' + d['Min'].astype(str).str[:10])
)
```

Comment: I agree that it is very subjective (that explains the downvotes I guess) but you gave me a very good starting point as I was struggling with chaining the filter and the creation of new column . Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Drop 'Date' line gave me an error. When I deleted that line and ran the code again, saw that the result does not include 'Date'. I am baffled

Comment: Try to remove `as_index=False` in the groupby and use `reset_index()` as you originally did. Now this wasn't really the original question, maybe you should provide a clear reproducible input/output if you want me to ensure all the code is working ;)